# can eclipse CDT be used in place of vc++ inorder to call C++ library in node.js by using SWIG?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, eclipse-cdt, swig

I have a C++ library which I want to call in node.js.
For that I opted for SWIG. But it requires to use visual studio c++.
My preference is eclipse CDT. Is there any way SWIG be used with eclipse?
Also is there any other tool or Addon that could help interfacing between node.js and c++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't require that you use Visual Studio as your IDE, only that you use the MSVC toolchain as MinGW and MSVC are not ABI compatible. For using the MSVC toolchain from within Eclipse see [this guide](http://codewriterstips.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/using-microsoft-c-compiler-with-eclipse.html).